# Changing Community Default Page

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder

I'm creating a maintenance splash page for my community and I wanted to change the default page of the community to point to it. Under Workspaces, I went to "Login and Registration" and searched for my page under the "Login Page Setup" section.

[image]

When I click the magnifying glass icon and search for the page name I can't find it. The maintenance splash page is public and published in the community. Is there another setting to get pages to show under "Login Page Type"?

Answer (score 0):

Community Workspaces or Mgmt > Administration | Pages > click on search icon next to Service Not Available ([docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_sna_page.htm&type=5))